# Systemd Process Cannot Open Ipc Socket When Indirectly Executing i3-msg ‘restart’

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, i3

I am on Arch Linux and have written my own service that runs on systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description=my service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myservice
Environment=DANS_CONFIG=/home/user/.config/dans/myconfig.toml

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The service runs fine until it executes a script via (rust code):

```
Command::new("sh").arg("-c").arg("/home/user/.config/scripts/i3change.py").output()
```

The program that gets executed does the following (python):

```
import os
os.system('i3-msg restart')
```

And I get the following output via systemctl log:
`i3-msg: Could not connect to i3 on socket /tmp/i3-ipc.sock: No such file or directory`

But when I run the i3-msg command from my terminal, everything works. I also tried changing group and user of the python script that gets executed by the service but it does not help.

How can I successfully get the systemd service invoked script to run `i3-msg restart`?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. It seems, IPC socket is created per user in `/run/user/{id}/i3` and (also) has some kind of session digits in filename. So if you run `i3-msg` as that user (by ssh or user's systemd service, where your shell session doesn't have `I3SOCK` variable), you should execute something like

```
i3-msg --socket=`ls /run/user/1000/i3/ipc-socket.*` restart
```

Looks awful by all means, but works well.